# Нужен ли для работы по протоколу веб соккет отдельный tcp соккет?

Tags: сервер, websocket, http-server

Нужен ли для работы по протоколу веб соккет отдельный tcp соккет? Или работа может осуществляться по тому же соккету, что и http? Иными слоами, сервер должен открывать под протокол веб соккет новые tcp соккет, или можно просто выделить отдельный поток и работать по тому же соккету что и http?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104891/discussion-on-question-by-denver-toha--------).